# Yaml: can we apply a prefix to a whole yaml file/document?

Tags: yaml

I have a document like this:

```
---
prefix1:
  prefix2:
    a:
      b:
        a: 'x'
      c:
        b: 'y'
      d:
        c: 'z'
    b:
      b:
        a: 'x'
      c:
        b: 'y'
      d:
        c: 'z'
    c:
      b:
        a: 'x'
      c:
        b: 'y'
      d:
        c: 'z'
```

The whole document will be nested under `prefix1.prefix2` and for various reasons I can't change that easily (different tools using Yaml and the same document as source)

Is there a way to rewrite this document so that I don't have as much indentation to handle?

Something like this?

```
DocumentPrefix=prefix1.prefix2
---
a:
  b:
    a: 'x'
  c:
    b: 'y'
  d:
    c: 'z'
b:
  b:
    a: 'x'
  c:
    b: 'y'
  d:
    c: 'z'
c:
  b:
    a: 'x'
  c:
    b: 'y'
  d:
    c: 'z'
```

Comment: AFAIK yaml is just a data serialization format. I think there is no way to change it without "break" anything. You could write a script or something to generate the original one, from your "reduced" version

Comment: yes that's what I thought unfortunatly it's not convenient in my case to manage 2 distinct files (I would rather use JSON for the source if going this path btw)

Comment: So, I guess you have just two choices: keep the first version of your yaml format. or modify programs using that file (I guess the last one is not an option...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YAML cannot do data transformation, so what you want to do is not possible. If the indentation bugs you, you can use flow-style collections:

```
---
{ prefix1: { prefix2: {
a: {
  b: {a: 'x'},
  c: {b: 'y'},
  d: {c: 'z'}
},
b: {
  b: {a: 'x'},
  c: {b: 'y'},
  d: {c: 'z'},
},
c: {
 b: {a: 'x'},
 c: {b: 'y'},
 d: {c: 'z'}
}
}}}
```

Comment: by chance can we mix both styles at the same time? not so sure

Comment: You can use flow style anywhere within block style, but once you've entered flow style, you need to keep it in all nested nodes.